# Unable to put up kylo service

Tags: postgresql, kylo

I am trying to to install Kylo from scratch. I am accessing postgresql from a remote machine. I am able to access postgresql on the remote machine from my machine. But I can't put up the kylo service. 
Here is my kylo_service.log file

[image: Log file]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the following properties are set correctly in your kylo-services/conf/application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.username=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_USERNAME>
spring.datasource.password=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_PASSWORD>

hive.datasource.username=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_USERNAME>
hive.metastore.datasource.username=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_USERNAME>
hive.metastore.datasource.password=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_PASSWORD>

nifi.service.mysql.database_user=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_USERNAME>
nifi.service.mysql.password=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_PASSWORD>
nifi.service.kylo_mysql.database_user=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_USERNAME>
nifi.service.kylo_mysql.password=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_PASSWORD>

#Note: The value for this property is the password for the dladmin user.
nifi.service.kylo_metadata_service.rest_client_password=<REPLACE_ME_WITH_PASSWORD>

modeshape.datasource.username=${spring.datasource.username}
modeshape.datasource.password=${spring.datasource.password}
metadata.datasource.username=${spring.datasource.username}
metadata.datasource.password=${spring.datasource.password}
```

http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/AdditionalConfiguration.html